# Possible to send a message via twilio conversation api at a specific time?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I know that as of 8/24/22, you can send text message at a specific time using the messaging API. However, I'd like to know if the exact same functionality is also available if you're using twilio conversations?

I didn't see that in API docs but would like someone to confirm officially. It'd be a nice feature to have if someone is ONLY using conversations to send messages back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's no such functionality in Conversations Product. The customer could implement scheduling on their side.
And there's a hacky workaround. The customer may use timers (https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/states-timers) and webhooks. Set a timer for moving conversation into 'inactive' state and then when timer caused moving Conversations into 'inactive' state, use 'onConversationStateUpdated' webhook to send a new message.